Capacitor CapGo Native Audio TypeError: this.notifyListeners is not a function
NOTE:
this error happens on the web only, on the web version of the capacitor plugin. I locally cloned the plugin repository and checked and the method should theoretically exist.
This is the package with which the error occurs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capgo/native-audio
I am getting errors like below
TypeError: this.notifyListeners is not a function
triggered from this method:
Audio.onEnded
after upgrading to

capacitor v6
(ionic v8)
(angular v17)


plugin version:
"@capgo/native-audio": "^6.4.4",

Here is my native-audio usage:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { getIsSoundEffectsOn$ } from './preferences';
import { NativeAudio } from '@capgo/native-audio';
import { Haptics, ImpactStyle } from '@capacitor/haptics';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AudioService {

  public isSoundEffectsOn = false;

  constructor() {
    this.preloadAudio('click', 'assets/sounds/click.mp3');
    this.preloadAudio('toggle', 'assets/sounds/toggle.mp3');
    this.preloadAudio('success', 'assets/sounds/success.wav');
    this.preloadAudio('failure', 'assets/sounds/failure.wav');

    getIsSoundEffectsOn$().then(isOn => {
      this.isSoundEffectsOn = isOn;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching sound effects preference:', error);
    });
  }

  private preloadAudio(assetId: string, assetPath: string): void {
    NativeAudio.preload({
      assetId,
      assetPath,
      audioChannelNum: 1,
      isUrl: false
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(`Preloaded ${assetId} successfully.`);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(`Error preloading ${assetId}:`, error);
    });
  }

  private async playAudio(assetId: string) {
    if (this.isSoundEffectsOn) {
      try {
        await NativeAudio.play({ assetId });
        console.log(`Playing ${assetId}.`);
      } catch (error) {
        if (assetId !== 'click') {
          console.error(`Error playing ${assetId}:`, error);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Sound effects are off. Not playing ${assetId}.`);
    }
  }

  public click(): void {
    Haptics.impact({ style: ImpactStyle.Light });
    this.playAudio('click');
  }

  public toggle(): void {
    Haptics.impact({ style: ImpactStyle.Light });
    this.playAudio('toggle');
  }

  public success(): void {
    Haptics.impact({ style: ImpactStyle.Medium });
    this.playAudio('success');
  }

  public failure(): void {
    this.playAudio('failure');
  }
}

used with a directive:
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {AudioService} from '../services/audio-service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickSound]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ClickSoundDirective {
  constructor(private audioService: AudioService) {
  }
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(){
    this.audioService.click();
  }
}

Tested on:
Chrome MacOS ARM
Safari MacOS ARM
